# vb.net select statement with parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid

Hi all I am having a weird problem on a aspx page.

I have a select statement where the where clause has 2 options

The result of the query should populate a datagrid

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    [Last Name], [First Name], SSN, 
    [Box Label], [Original Box Number],
    [Student ID], FolderName, DOB, [Transcript On File Y/N],
    UserID, [School ID], 
    [Box Number], [School Name], Comment, SW, Code, Descrip 
FROM 
    Main 
WHERE 
    ([Last Name] = ?) OR ([First Name] = ?)
```

When I put just one of the parameters (ie: lastname) nothing gets populated to the datagrid, but if I put data in both parameter is fills the datagrid with data.

I tested the select statement to verify that it does get data when I choose one or the other, but when I run it online it requires both fields to have data.

very weird...

Comment: Is there an error from the database or the provider when only one parameter is supplied?  I imagine it would be a syntax error or something of that nature to have a placeholder for a parameter and no parameter to put there.  Even if it's logically not going to be used, I imagine *something* needs to be provided for any given placeholder.

Comment: No errors come up I put a try catch I ran a debug going to try a trace to see if anything comes up

Comment: very strange thing happened if I put correct data in one field and anything on the other field data shows up, but if I leave it blank I get nothing. maybe I should put whitespace as a default

Comment: checking for null values then assigning " " to it worked, but I know this isn't the correct way to do it. Oh well